# jquery slideToggle from center of div

Tags: jquery, center, slidetoggle

I want to have an effect like jquery slideToggle(), but want the effect to origin from the center or middle of applied the div, not default 'top'. Is it possible?or can somebody guide me to some plugins where I can get that effect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us some illustrations of what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  `toggle` with jqueryui's [clip-effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/clip-effect/)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need jquery ui for that. just center you element vertically and slideUp will animate up but gets centered. the result is a clip effect.